# "Test failed: Error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in Composer - Appgyver

Tags: php, angularjs, steroids, appgyver, supersonic

I am creating an App in Appgyver Composer.
I have a PHP file which perfect and gives appropriate response when triggered. I tried making this a service by putting appropriate credentials. However, the test returned the following error :

```
"Test failed: Error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
```

Any idea how I can set Access  Control Allow Login to "*" in Composer? The tag already exists in the php file on my server.

I have also added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in header to "*", hoping that might do the trick.

Anyone did anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

In your php script, set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the value of the calling domain (the value of the `Origin` header). If you don't care who has access, you can just send back the `Origin` header from the request as so:

```
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] !== null ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '*';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);
```

[HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

> when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

Comment: This generates a 500 error. Any  clue what went wrong? Permissions are set to 777 for simplicity for now.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code, the 500 error did go away but the main error still persists when I try to run a back-end service test.

Comment: Can you log the http headers exchanged during the request ?

Comment: I used a work around. Used GET instead of POST in my server file. Works like a charm now, for some reason. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround. The POST method on the server was creating the  issue, apparently. I used GET method and it started working perfectly. You might wanna consider that later.